# Plotting barplot with bars by grouped/colored by group names

Tags: r, plot, colors, histogram

Well with this dataset in CSV format,

```
GO Biological Process,regulation of lipid metabolic process,1.87E-35
GO Biological Process,acute inflammatory response,3.21E-37
GO Biological Process,response to insulin stimulus,1.05E-38
GO Biological Process,steroid metabolic process,4.19E-39
GO Biological Process,cholesterol metabolic process,1.19E-40
GO Biological Process,cellular response to chemical stimulus,5.87E-42
GO Biological Process,alcohol metabolic process,5.27E-43
GO Biological Process,sterol metabolic process,2.61E-43
GO Biological Process,lipid homeostasis,1.12E-44
GO Biological Process,response to peptide hormone stimulus,1.29E-45
GO Biological Process,monocarboxylic acid metabolic process,2.33E-54
GO Biological Process,cellular ketone metabolic process,5.46E-74
GO Biological Process,carboxylic acid metabolic process,2.41E-76
GO Biological Process,organic acid metabolic process,5.30E-79
Pathway Commons,FOXA transcription factor networks,7.40E-61
Pathway Commons,FOXA2 and FOXA3 transcription factor networks,1.39E-64
Transcription Factor Targets,"Targets of HNF6, identified by ChIP-chip in hepatocytes",1.77E-32
Transcription Factor Targets,"Targets of HNF1alpha, identified by ChIP-chip in hepatocytes",3.87E-65
Transcription Factor Targets,"Targets of HNF4alpha, identified by ChIP-chip in hepatocytes",1.38E-131
```

I would like to be able to create a plot (barplot?) that looks like this :
[image]

where the three different groups in column 1 are grouped together with the same color and the 3rd column is sorted from biggest to smalest. 
The plot above is made with excel but I would like to be able to make it properly in R. 
So far all I am getting is the 2nd and 3nd column plotted, I can't get the bars grouped by the 1st column.

---

Well I have tried ggplot as recommended. This is what I got (it looks brilliant btw) :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(tmp, aes(x=tmp$V2, y=log(tmp$V3), fill=tmp$V1)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
coord_flip() +
scale_y_log()
```

[image: how]

However, I need to find out how to "reverse" the axis such as [0, 1e-130] (eg. the bars go from left to right like in my example above)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is reasonably straight-forward with `ggplot` in the `ggplot2` package.  You can achieve this by specifying the fill colour in your plot, and mapping a column in your data to the fill, i.e. `aes(..., fill=group)`:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(
    label=LETTERS[1:10],
    value=10:1,
    group=letters[c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)]
)

dat
   label value group
1      A    10     a
2      B     9     a
3      C     8     b
4      D     7     b
5      E     6     b
6      F     5     c
7      G     4     c
8      H     3     c
9      I     2     c
10     J     1     c

ggplot(dat, aes(x=label, y=value, fill=group)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: that looks really nice. Am I not familiar with ggplot at all but am gonna try it - Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: God, ggplot is a whole new world ! Very interesting but seems a lot more complex...